# Cannot click "New Partition Table..." during installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with windows Vista and when I get to the "installation type" menu on the Ubuntu installer I cant click the "New Partition Table..." button. It's greyed out like in this picture.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to click the `+` button?

Comment: Yes, i can click it.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I can click it but after a few seconds the program freezes.

Comment: Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred This is the result. http://pastebin.com/CyeyGpBr

Comment: Drive is fully allocated. Best to use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partition to make unallocated space and reboot immediately so Windows can run chkdsk. But if Vista is hibernated or already needs chkdsk, the Linux NTFS driver cannot mount it to see it. You also can manually partition / & swap preferable in an extended partition and use Something else to choose(change) partitions that already exist. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation